Can you hold someone accountable for enacting policies while under the influence of foreign manipulation?
I assume that it is illegal in most countries to work on behalf of foreign governments, while holding political offices in that same country. It doesn't matter whether you are being paid by that foreign government or are sent by them, which would be corruption or a form of espionage.
But what about politicians who follow foreign parties/governments ideologies, because they became victims of targeted manipulation campaigns of said party/government? The act of influencing politicians of other countries for a governments own gain is prohibited via domestic laws of many countries as well.
But can the target/victim of those covert manipulation campaigns be held accountable for helping foreign governments reach their goals?

One can pass laws to hold anyone accountable for anything, but you might consider specifying how you would define that concept. Accepting money or quid pro quo gifts is easy to recognize. Secretive collusion, not so hard. But what is being influenced? If Vladimir Putin writes an article for Russia Today hoping to persuade foreign politicians who read it, then I read it, think he is correct, and enact a policy similar to that which he advocates, have I been unduly influenced? Does it matter whether his reasoning is correct or not?

If I had to think of a country which does this, the DPRK would come to my mind. But in most countries, holding an opinion is not illegal just because someone else also held it. Someone who claims to be convinced by the internal logic of a foreign position, rather than getting bribed to support it, would be allowed to do that.
This especially applies to legislators, who usually have special immunity for speeches or votes in parliament. Rules may be different for members of the executive who took an oath of office -- "falling for" foreign propaganda might at the very least put their judgement in question, which could cost them their job.

Less formally, happens in Belarus too.

I didn't think of it this way, when I asked the question. Falling for foreign propaganda might put their judgement in question but the person themself is not liable for their possibly influenced opinion. Thanks for the answer! :)

@Caeleste, things which are legal might still put a security clearance into question, for example.


But can the target/victim of those covert manipulation campaigns be
held accountable for helping foreign governments reach their goals?

Not through a legal process, although the voters can choose not to re-election someone who does so if they see fit.
In politics, the foundational question is what the objectives of a government should be, and inevitably, this will help some foreign governments and hurt others. Therefore, the law does not punish politicians  for the choices about those objectives that they make. Politicians are immune from liability for their discretionary official actions, if they aren't procured by corruption in which the politician is personally involved. This is a universal or near universal rule in genuine democracies.

The question is not tagged "united-states".  I assume your answer is meant to be either about the US or other countries with genuine elections.  You may want to tag the answer then.  There are are many (mostly undemocratic) countries where simply being accused to be under the influence of foreign adversaries is enough to get in legal trouble.

@RadicallyReasonable This is why I clarify the scope of the answer in the last sentence. There is no tag for "all democratic countries." It is not an exclusively U.S. answer.

"Politicians are immune from liability for their discretionary official actions, if they aren't procured by corruption in which the politician is personally involved." Or they are the president of the United States.  If a payment is made for something other than an official act, then it wouldn't be bribery, and if it is for an official act, then the recent SCOTUS decision seems to suggest that the president has immunity.
